# system.data.oledb.oledbexception data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

I Try to check if the number exist in the table, when i use string and text in the database there is no problem but when i use a decimal (12345.5) and number in the database i have a data type mismatch in criteria expression.
My database is MSAccess.

```
string OleDbValuecheck =
    "SELECT Table1.Number FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Number =  '"+ (result) + "' ";
OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(OleDbValuecheck, conn);
OleDbDataAdapter sd2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2);
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
sd2.Fill(dt2);
if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yet another case where using SQL Paramaters as you should would avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

Table1.Number sounds like a number ;-) but you treat it as a character field in the SQL (you enclose it in quotes). Remove those quotes. Also, your C# code tries to concatenate `result` with implicit conversion to string, which may result in unexpected values like scientific notation, make it explicit with a predictable format.

```
string OleDbValuecheck =
    "SELECT Table1.Number FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Number = "+ (result.ToString("0.00"));
```

We don't know what is/can be in `result`; make sure that the format you choose in the conversion (ToString()) does not lose any precision.

Update: Also, you said you are taking `result` from the Text property of an MsAccess form textbox control. This property returns the text displayed on the form, as formatted, therefore it would have thousands delimiters (if the underlying number is 1234.5 and the textbox's format is set to 'Standard', for example, the .Text property would return `1,234.50`. I suggest that you change TextBox.Text to Textbox.Value, or remove the thousands delimiters by `result.Replace(',','')`

Comment: Now i get the following error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (comma) in query expression

Comment: Show us what is in 'result'. Also show us the resulting entire query (SQL text) formed.

Comment: I suspect that `result` might actually be a string and it might have thousands delimiters (commas)

Comment: This is my whole message of the error:System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (comma) in query expression 'Table1.Number= 4754,1'.'

Comment: As you can see the value in `result` is not a valid number (it contains a comma character). `Table1.Number` must have been defined as a number and msaccess attempts to convert `4754,1` to a number so that it can compare, but fails. Remove the comma.

Comment: Can you confirm how `result` is declared ? string? a numeric type?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't figure it out, I try from a textbox the value to compare with the value in the table.
How do I get the value of correctly from the textbox?

Comment: is `result` a c# variable or the name of a textbox on an MsAccess form?  if C#, how is it declared? Can you show more of your code in your question (include the bits about how `result` came to exist. If we assume that `result` is string, and it will have thousands delimiters (as your error message shows), remove them with `result.Replace(',','')`

Comment: Tinazmu many thanks for the help and the result.Replace(',','') solution is working perfectly !!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do clumsy replacement. Do it right and apply the *InvariantCulture* that always uses a dot as the decimal separator:

```cs
Decimal result = 12345.5M;
var invariantCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string resultText = result.ToString(invariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(resultText);
// 12345.5

// then:

string OleDbValuecheck =
    "SELECT Table1.Number FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Number = " + resultText + "";
```